# Find correct URL for WMTS Time layer for Leaflet

Tags: qgis, leaflet, wmts, time

So I have this WMTS-Layer (the GetCapabilities Request):

https://wmts.marine.copernicus.eu/teroWmts/GLOBAL_MULTIYEAR_WAV_001_032/cmems_mod_glo_wav_my_0.2_PT3H-i_202112?request=GetCapabilities&

Which comes from here: https://data.marine.copernicus.eu/product/GLOBAL_MULTIYEAR_WAV_001_032/services

The layer itself has time-information. When I put the GetCapabilities-request in QGIS as new WMTS-Layer I get all the layers and a direct hint that it has time-information.
Now I am really unsure how to use that WMTS-Layer with Leaflet. I'd like to be able to specify the time and request the appropriate tiles. A sample request in QGIS looks like this:

http://wmts.marine.copernicus.eu/teroWmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=&LAYER=GLOBAL_MULTIYEAR_WAV_001_032%2Fcmems_mod_glo_wav_my_0.2_PT3H-i_202112%2FVHM0&STYLE=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG%3A4326&TILEMATRIX=1&time=2021-12-31T21%3A00%3A00Z&TILEROW=1&TILECOL=2

What I tried so far is the following:

```
    L.tileLayer
      .wms(
        "http://wmts.marine.copernicus.eu/teroWmts/?service=WMTS&version=1.0.0",
        {
          layers:
            "GLOBAL_MULTIYEAR_WAV_001_032/cmems_mod_glo_wav_my_0.2_PT3H-i_202112/VHM0",
            time: "2021-12-31"
        }
      )
      .addTo(map);

and 

    L.tileLayer
      .wms(
        "http://wmts.marine.copernicus.eu/teroWmts/?service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&request=GetTile",
        {
          layers: "GLOBAL_MULTIYEAR_WAV_001_032/cmems_mod_glo_wav_my_0.2_PT3H-i_202112/VHM0",
          time: "2021-12-31"
        }
      )
      .addTo(map);
```

Yet, none of the above worked as its not pointing to the resource:/

Comment: oh yes sorry, of course. I added what I tried so far!

Comment: What response do you get from the server?

Comment: WMTS stands for web map **tiled** service. Not time. Revisit your assumptions about the service.

Comment: Which assumptions exactly? Sorry I got a little confused with the naming... But there are wms services which are time aware as far as I know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The layer you are trying to display is not WMS layer, so you can't display it as `L.tileLayer.wms` layer. It's WMTS layer, which means it's raster tile layer, so you have to use plain `L.tileLayer` layer.

Simple code to display it can look something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 0,
  crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326
});

var template =
  'https://wmts.marine.copernicus.eu/teroWmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=&LAYER={layer}&STYLE=&FORMAT=image/png&TILEMATRIXSET={tileMatrixSet}&TILEMATRIX={z}&time={time}&TILEROW={y}&TILECOL={x}'

var layer = L.tileLayer(template, {
  layer: 'GLOBAL_MULTIYEAR_WAV_001_032/cmems_mod_glo_wav_my_0.2_PT3H-i_202112/VHM0',
  tileMatrixSet: 'EPSG:4326',
  time: '2021-12-31',
  noWrap: true
}).addTo(map);
```

That's how it looks like then at zoom 0:

[image]

Comment: that is brilliant!! Thank you so much:) I'll try it myself later. It really does help a lot:)